# Pandas Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_players.loc[df_players['Player']=='Vitor Gabriel'][['Points']]
```

prints:

```
           Points
407           0.0
18805         0.0
19634         0.0
20459         7.2
21285         0.0
22111         0.0
22936         0.0
```

Now If I do:

```
a1_points = df_players.loc[df_players['Player']=='Vitor Gabriel'][['Points']]
a1_points['RollingAvg'] = a1_points.rolling(window=4, center=False).mean()
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
```

---

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second line need to convert to series first

```
a1_points['RollingAvg'] = a1_points.Points.rolling(window=4, center=False).mean()
```